# Azure Container Instance Windows Version Wrong

Tags: azure, docker

I create Docker image on Windows 10 for an empty .Net Core web app. Using Windows containers on Docker Desktop, of course, and I pulled the Microsoft/dotnet image from Docker repository. Then I register and upload the image to Azure Registry, everything is fine.

Now I go to my Azure registry and use that image -> Run Instance -> and then specify parameters to create a Container Instance....after a while I get this messagege:

```
OsVersionNotSupported
The Windows version of image 'mytestcontainers.azurecr.io/testdocker:latest' is not supported. The supported Windows versions are: '10.0.14393'.
```

So obviously it seems as if the Azure container instance cannot run any other Windows but 10.0.14393, but how do I specify that specific Windows version and where?

I have seen that I can pull the Docker image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver and then specify the tag to pull the specific Windows build, but is that the way to do it? Is it going to change the Windows version that Docker is going to use when creating my image with .Net Core runtime?
Thanks.

Comment: Seemed as if this would be the answer, but no, it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610319/whats-the-correct-windows-base-image-for-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-containers-on

Comment: I got bit by this with 1803 image which works on my machine of course. I know you tried but I'm grabbing at straws too. Will let yo know if the suggestino to target the base image, not a tag, does the job.

Comment: Any update?  I'm having the same issue

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. 

This posts mentions an image for ASPNET but not .Net Core runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671181/cant-find-a-good-docker-image-for-windows-version-14393