# Windows containers in Azure Container Instances - which base image to use?

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers, azure-container-instances, azure-acr

I'm trying to get a very simple .net core console app to run in a windows container on Azure Container Instances but I'm having soo many problems.

First I attempted using the `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime` as the base image but I can the error regarding the wrong windows version which has been reported at [Azure Container Instance Windows Version Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334642/azure-container-instance-windows-version-wrong). 
I've tried numerous different base images, some which run on my local machine and some that don't but I still can't find a base image which has dot net core on it and is a valid windows version for the ACI service.  Can anyone point me in the direction of what base image I should be using? Or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick?
TIA

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS base 
WORKDIR /app 

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY [<obfuscated>.csproj", "<obfuscated>./"] 
RUN dotnet restore "<obfuscated>.csproj" 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR "/src/<obfuscated>." 
RUN dotnet build "<obfuscated>.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "<obfuscated>..csproj" -c Release -o /app 
FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<obfuscated>.dll"]
```

Comment: Where are you building the .net project?

Comment: On my machine which is Windows 10. Does that make a difference?

Comment: could you share the docker file in your question? Yes it makes a difference if the SDK and runtime versions mismatch you may hit this issue. Please, update your question with `Dockerfile`

Comment: ```FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY [<obfuscated>.csproj", "<obfuscated>./"]
RUN dotnet restore "<obfuscated>.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/<obfuscated>."
RUN dotnet build "<obfuscated>.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "<obfuscated>..csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<obfuscated>.dll"]```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to edit the question so I've copied it as a comment.  Annoyingly it's lost the formatting, but hopefully you get the gist ;)

Comment: use this as base image `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime` and update it it worked.

Comment: Didn't work.  I still get this error:
```{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"OsVersionNotSupported\",\r\n \"message\": \"The Windows version of image 'efpsdocker.azurecr.io/dockertest:v1' is not supported. The supported Windows versions are: '10.0.14393'.\"\r\n }\r\n}"}]}```

Comment: ok try this one `microsoft/windowsservercore` sorry it;'s a hit and trial issue can't do much. This sh** is not documented anywhere. :(

Comment: Yes, that's my frustration with this. I don't get why I'm just using Microsoft technologies but none of them work together. 
I'm attempting to deploy using a non docker solution at the moment but if i get no joy I'll try out that image.  Thanks for you help though ;)